# Different behavior between 1.6 and 1.7 getRuntime().exec

Tags: java

A little mystery here, we are using a third party image server that started breaking under 1.6.0_45, research determined that it was caused by changed to getRuntime().exec.

Release notes for 1.6.0_45, note the section, Changes to Runtime.exec
 http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/6u45-relnotes-1932876.html

These changes were supposed to be available in 1.7.25 and later.

Now to the mystery, the exception below in thrown with 1.6.0_45, but not with 1.7.0_45. The exception appears to be directly related to the exec changes. Why doesn't it break in 1.7.0_45? Side note, there is easy work around, install Java into a directory that does not have spaces.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Executable
name has embedded quote, split the arguments
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.isQuoted(ProcessImpl.java:52)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.getExecutablePath(ProcessImpl.java:85)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:127)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:28)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:452)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:593)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:431)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:328)
    at com.corda.pcagent.f.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: The top of the Exception is missing, please add it to your question.

Comment: First of all what system are you running your programs? What is the command line that you are calling. The very last thing to check is some sort of problem on Java. It is most likely something related with the SO or some configuration.

Comment: Window Server 2003 or 2008. The commands lines are exactly the same for the 1.6 and 1.7 calls. All I do is swap out the which version of Java is kicking off the process. Note, that the failure is happening inside of a third party library that I have no control over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> These changes were supposed to be available in 1.7.25 and later.

In fact, the change was introduced in 1.7.21.

In 1.7.25 they introduced a system  property called `"jdk.lang.Process.allowAmbigousCommands"`.  If you set that property to `"true"` on the command line, it re-enables the old (pre-1.7.21) Windows-specific behaviour for `Runtime.exec(String)`.

Maybe they / someone has done this for the application ... which might explain why it is unexpectedly working on 1.7.45.

Comment: The reason is that unlike the [reference](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u25-relnotes-1955741.html#jruntime) looks like, the default behavior is like `true`. I did a step-by-step debugging and it will assume `true` when this property is not specified.

Comment: Holger that makes sense, I wonder if they did that on purpose. Even though the doc implies it's false.

Comment: Most probably to get more old code working. Note that the security issues are still fixed: when a `SecurityManager` is installed, the implementation treats this flag as `false` unconditionally, regardless of the presence or value of the system property.